# Allowing users to add computer to AD and manage computer

Tags: active-directory

As a software company, we need our support staff to be able to run multiple instances of our software on separate machines.

The way we usually do this is to clone a virtual machine, add it to our AD server, and have them use a local admin account on the clone system. As our  system admin, some of this requires my assistance.

What I would like to do is:

1. Allow specified users to add computers to (a sub-domain of) our local domain. I know they can add a few, but I would like an unlimited number of additions.
2. Allow the same users to have admin privileges on the computers added, without  having to change the configuration on the computer

Is there any way I can do this? It has been suggested that I can create an Organisation Unit in our domain to allow this, but beyond this, I haven't a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

1. Create permission group called ACL-Local Admin for Devs
2. Add your developers to the group
3. Create new GPO and add the group to it and assign it to your devs OU. Edit the GPO as following:

   Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Management -> Add Workstations to domain

For users to become local admins is a bit more challenging if the computer remains in the default Computers OU.

You can redirect Computers to a new OU and give that OU permissions to the "ACL-Local Admin for Devs". You can move your computers to correct OU with your AD access as required

[Redirect default Computers OU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/324949/redirecting-the-users-and-computers-containers-in-active-directory-dom)

Run the Redircmp.exe file at a command prompt by using the following syntax, where container-dn is the distinguished name of the organizational unit that will become the default location for newly created computer objects that are created by down-level APIs:

```
redircmp container-dn container-dn
```

**Give permissions via GPO**

Edit the same GPO as before and attach it to the Computers OU
Computer Configuration -> Preferences -> Comtrol Panel Settings -> Local Users and Groups -> New -> Local Group

[image: Add domain group into Local Administrators built-in group]